# bubble apear when tap and hold tableview cell like taping song in ipod in iphone 

Tags: iphone, sdk, ipod

i am working on one music app where we can import music from iPod and play, in native app (iPod) in iPhone IOS 5 when tap and hold on any song or playlist a bubble appear with information, i want to implement that feature in my table view cell, but not getting any idea how to do it.

Comment: Try searching on UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Comment: through UILongPressGestureRecognizer can help but can not get what i want have you look in the native music app that what i am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement these 3 methods, it should be similar to what you want.

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender
```

Hope it helps

Comment: just implemented them, but they are showing cut,copy and paste option in bubble i want to show same data in it.